# GPS data RMC GSr

Tags: gps, nmea

I set up the server to trace the data sent from GPS device. And the output is:

```
GET /tr206.php?RMC=GSr,354660042186281,4,5,00,,3,011313,031703,E10538.9146,N1846.2847,5,20.28,340,10,0.7,91*5b! HTTP/1.1
```

Could you please help me to understand what are the values meaning?

Comment: Anny reason why you have removed the accept, since there is no other ranswer?

Comment: Actually, I still don't have information of each fields between comma.

Comment: The first fields "GSr,354660042186281,4,5,00,,3" are proprietary, for sure no one will answer you. The rest is simple, as define in NMEA RMC

Answer (score 1):

Your ouput is a RMC sentence defined in NMEA 0183.

```
RMC=GSr,354660042186281,4,5,00,,3,011313,031703,E10538.9146,N1846.2847,5,20.28,340,10,0.7,91*5b
```

But it has some extensions, like `"GSr"`, which is not a pure RMC format. So for reverse engineering you should start on the end of the string `"*5b"` which is the RMC checksum, and work to the begin of the line:

This is longitude: `E10538.9146`
This is latitide: `N1846.2847`

for more info search for NMEA format description.
For example here [RMC](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC), 
or better [here](http://home.mira.net/~gnb/gps/nmea.html#latlong) where you find the description of the format of the latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see any template like I mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183. It seems that this is a correct place: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC

Comment: There is no official place because theoretically you would have to buy the spec. But I updated two links in my answer.